# How to parse delimited field in FileMaker Pro into a new table

Tags: filemaker

I have a field in my FileMaker Pro database that contains semi-colon delimited data in it so what I want to do is separate that data into a new table. if someone could point me in the right direction that would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to write a script that splits the text into lines (using `GetValue()`), then splits each line by semicolon (`Substitute( $line, ";", "¶" )`, then `GetValue()` from the resulting list), and finally posts the data into the other table (Go to Layout, New Record, Set Field). Can sketch the whole script, if you want.

I'd write it like that:

```
Go to Layout( My Table )
Go to Record/Request/Page[ First ]
# Loop over records
Loop
    Set Variable[ $line, 1 ]
    # Loop over lines
    Loop
      Exit Loop If[ ValueCount( My Table::My Field ) < $line ]
      #
      # Get line values
      Set Variable[ $fields, 
          Substitute( GetValue( My Table::My Field, $line ), ";", "¶" ) ]
      # ...
      Go to Layout( My Target Table )
      New Record/Request
      Set Field[ My Target Table::Foo, GetValue( $fields, 1 ) ]
      Set Field[ My Target Table::Foo, GetValue( $fields, 2 ) ]
      Go to Layout( My Table )
      # 
      Set Variable[ $line, $line + 1 ] 
    End Loop
    Go to Record/Request/Page[ Next, Exit After Last ]
End Loop
Go to Layout( original layout )
```

Comment: ok so in my script I it do a find replace changing ";" to "¶" which makes paragraphs and use GetValue ( listOfValues ; valueNumber ) so listOfValues would = my modified field how do I keep track or loop through the paragraphs

Comment: Added an example script to the post.